# How to convert this JS function to Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to learn Coffeescript, and at the moment I'm in the process of porting some existing JS to it to test things out.

I know the default syntax for a function is like this:

```
square = (x) -> x * x
```

Which would give

```
  square = function(x) {
  return x * x;
};
```

I'm trying to convert this JS:

```
 function updateViewportDimensions() {
    var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
    return {
      width: x,
      height: y
    }
  }
```

But I keep getting crazy output. I think if someone could show me the valid corresponding CS it'd help my learning a lot. I've looked around but can't find anything that helps me with this example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check there - js2coffee.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
updateViewportDimensions = ->
  w = window
  d = document
  e = d.documentElement
  g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
  x = w.innerWidth or e.clientWidth or g.clientWidth
  y = w.innerHeight or e.clientHeight or g.clientHeight    
  width: x
  height: y
```